# Where do teams chats actually get stored if your mailbox is on-prem?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Where do Microsoft Teams chats actually get stored if your mailbox is on-prem?  From https://www.contentandcode.com/blog/how-to-backup-microsoft-teams/ it suggests that individual 1:1 chats will be stored in the user's mailbox but only if the mailbox is in Office 365.  Is this true even for hybrid environments where the user's mailbox is on-prem and AD/AAD is in sync?  When it doesn't store it in the mailbox, does Microsoft Teams store them somewhere else in the cloud, or locally where the Microsoft Teams client is installed?

Answer (score 0):

chat messages actually stores in azure blob storage and keeps a copy of chats and channel messages in exchange for journal purpose. so main data stores in azure storage.

if you want more details on chat and chat service please go through first 5mins of below tech video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6B4KraD-FM&t=2769s